# How do I write to an outer truecrypt volume when the inner volume protection prevents writng?

Tags: filesystem, usb-drive, truecrypt

#### In a nutshell

*After some time using the outer volume of a **hidden volume** in **Truecrypt** I cannot write to the outer volume anymore. The **protection of the inner volume always kicks in** before. How do I fix this?*

---

### Details

I'm using **truecrypt**'s two layered encryption of a **USB stick**. The outer container carries my semi-sensitive stuff while the inner hidden values has a bit more valuable information. **I use both, the inner and outer volume regularly and that is part of the problem**. Truecrypt can mount the outer volume for writing while **protecting the inner**. Usually the inner volume, when not protected this way (or mounted read-only) would be indistinguishable from free space. That is of course part of the **plausible deniability** scheme of truecrypt.

[image: Truecrypt outer volume]

At the beginning, everything worked as expected. I could copy and delete data to the outer volume as I pleased. Now it seams that I have written and deleted enough data to have **filled the outer volume once**. Despite the write protection Ubuntu tries now to write to the continuous "free space" that is the inner volume. It does that although enough other free space is on the outer volume. But on this free space there used to be data so its fragmented and the **file system write prefers continuous space**. The write on the continuous free space of the outer volume of course **fails (with the error message in the picture above) as Truecrypt's inner-volume-protection kicks in**.

### The Question

***I know this is expected behaviour, but is there a better way to write to the outer volume that does not attempt to write to the hidden free space at the end?***

The whole question could be more generally rephrased to: How do I control, where on a partition data is written in Ubuntu?

Comment: This would be a bug or rather a design defect in truecrypt.  They would need to patch the filesystem to avoid the areas actually used by the inner filesystem.

Comment: @psusi But then, wouldn't the hidden inner volume be more obvious? It could be easily detected by merely attempting to fill up the outer volume. As soon as the person noticed that "hey, the files are all magically avoiding writing to this spot," it would reveal the existence of the hidden inner volume. (The whole point of the inner volume is that it doesn't even appear to exist unless you specifically attempt to decode the _inner_ volume and get the password correct.)

Comment: If you have to make any explicit change to the configuration of the outer volume to protect the inner, then there is no point using an inner volume since you make it clear that it exists, and might as well have it exist safely as a separate volume. (I would question in general that truecrypt inner volumes serve any useful purpose, since the feature is so well known that any hostile party presented with a truecrypt volume is going to assume an inner volume exists regardless, plausible deniability be damned).

Comment: That is all true. However the hidden volume could be distributed across the whole memory area pseudo-randomly using the unlock key as a seed for distribution. This way Truecrypt would know what to protect while still looking random. Files are over written all the time so a hidden volume distributed in such a way would not be as obvious. Chronitis has a point, still the inner volume makes it harder for it might not even be there. That's not the point of my post however. I just want to use the inner volume again. It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude, that's how it works now... the driver won't let you write to the parts that hold the inner volume, but trying to causes the filesystem to error and go read-only.  And yes, this only works if you provide the super secret password for the inner volume.

Comment: @chronitis, you seem to misunderstand what the word plausible deniability means.. it doesn't matter whether they suspect there is an inner volume... they can't prove it, hence you can deny there is one and not get in legal trouble for having one.

Comment: @con-f-use Hmm, so that means that you could actually irritate anybody who wants your data by having a "dummy" inner volume, which would actually contain a large, useless file (such as an mp4 video of a Trollface, for example... :) whereas the actual secret files were stored on something/somewhere else entirely. (Wow... so many layers of fake-outs and deception...)

Comment: @psusi It is plausible that I have forgotten the password to my encrypted data, but nonetheless the law in a number of jurisdictions (wikipedia:Key_disclosure_law) provides that I can be penalised for not divulging it. This seems to reflect an unfortunately widespread attitude of guilty until proven innocent in encryption-related cases, which makes me suspect that where there is a well-known capability to store a second volume, plausible deniability and proper standards of evidence may not count for much.

Comment: I'd like to close commenting as off-topic. Also: why the down-vote?

Comment: @chronitis, no, you give them the password to the outer volume and it is plausible that is the only one there is, hence, you satisfied the requirement of the law.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how it works with ubuntu, but with windows you can try a defrag tool like "mydefrag" and move all your data to the beginning of your disk ("consolidate free disk space"). The position where to write new data will be set to the end of your existing data.

If all your data already IS at the beginning of your disk (so mydefrag does not move any data) and you still cannot write (although there should be space in the outer volume left) you need to make mydefrag make some data movement, e.g. by choosing the option "data disk monthly" and abort it as soon as the first file has been moved.

Edit: Works with FAT32. Don't know OP's filesystem. But FAT32 seems common to me for USB pendrives.

Comment: NTFS file systems belive that all data must be crammed up in as little contiguous space as possible and hence the need for defragmentation. ext4 inherently is fragmented from the free space point of view. it attempts to prevent file fragmentation but fragments freespace nevertheless. this is not what the OP is looking for.